# How to draw Inputs from Geometry nodes modifier in a panel

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, geometry-nodes

I am trying to draw the inputs of the Geometry Nodes modifier to a panel, and I tried doing this

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import (Panel)

class DRAW_PT_ModInputs(Panel):
    bl_label = "Draw Modifier Inputs"
    bl_idname = "DRAW_PT_ModInputs"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text = "Geometry Node inputs here")
        row = layout.row()
        GeoNodesModifier = context.active_object.modifiers.get("GeometryNodes")
        if GeoNodesModifier:
            row.prop(GeoNodesModifier.Input_5, "Density Max", text="Density")
        
        
 

classes = [DRAW_PT_ModInputs]   

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)



def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

and that gave me error `AttributeError: 'NodesModifier', object has no attribute 'Input_5'` and in another attempt I tried this `row.prop(GeoNodesModifier['Input_5'], "Density Max", text="Density")` but this is also not working and it gives error -

```
TypeError: UILayout.prop(): error with argument 1, "data" -  Function.data expected a AnyType type, not float
```

and this is how my Geometry Nodes Modifier looks like -

[image: Modifier screenshot]

and this is my Geometry Node tree -

[image: Geometry Nodetree screenshot]

I needed help regarding drawing the inputs from the Geometry Nodes modifier in my customized panel.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out the [style guide](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_best_practice.html#style-conventions)  under which the modifier instance variable would be named akin to `geom_modifier`  (_I  like using `gm` to reduce the verbosity_)  Camel case is used for class names. A variable named  `GeoNodesModifier`  will consistently be a type in any official blender UI code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The modifier input value is treated like a custom property.**

If you right click over the data field in the modifier and select "copy datapath", pasting will reveal

```
modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_5"]
```

Indicating it is a custom propoerty of the modifier named "Input_5".  A custom property named "prop" on object `ob` is shown in UI as

```
UILayout.prop(ob, '["prop"]')
```

Hence in this case.

```
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text = "Geometry Node inputs here")
        row = layout.row()
        gm = context.active_object.modifiers.get("GeometryNodes")
        if gm:
            row.prop(gm, '["Input_5"]',  text="Density")
```

Note

Check out the [style guide](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_best_practice.html#style-conventions) under which the modifier instance variable would be named akin to `geom_modifier` (I like using `gm` to reduce the verbosity) Camel case is used for class names. A variable named `GeoNodesModifier` will consistently be a type in any official blender UI code

Comment: That was fast :) Oh right, add commas around the list ! Clever. I don't know about the use of custom properties though. It would seem better to me if they were categorised in an `inputs` container and accessed like in node groups for instance. Using custom properties might clash with addons and so on. Idk

Comment: Agreed, fuddles the py console too.  Teething problem perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too worried, it's still a very young tool and they have time to improve the API and UI :) But unfortunately that will render this kind of answers outdated at every breaking update...

Comment: Also agreed. Will notice that like UI defined custom properties the `_RNA_UI`data is set. Changing the input / output node `default_value` sets the default of custom prop. `C.object.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]['_RNA_UI'].to_dict()`

Comment: @batFINGER aside from losing panel formatting can you think of any other reason not to do something like `for ip in gm.node_group.inputs: layout.prop(gm, f'["{ip.identifier}"]', text=ip.name) `

Comment: Very helpful, would have never thought of trying it like this.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from the GeoNodes modifier API, you access the node group (or tree, since every node tree is a group and every node group is a tree there) with `modifier.node_group`. This will give you access to the inputs and outputs, very much like all other node groups in Blender (Shader, Compositor, etc.)

You can then access the input by its Name, or its integer position in the inputs hierarchy. The former will break if you change the input name, while the latter will break if you reorder your inputs.

Replace your `row.prop` line with

```
row.prop(geom_modifier.node_group.inputs["Density Max"], "default_value", text="Density")
```

OR

```
row.prop(geom_modifier.node_group.inputs[1], "default_value", text="Density")
```

Result :

[image]

If you want more information from the API, check Python tooltips and developer extras in the preferences, and hover over fields to get more information about their relative path.

Comment: Hi, this is working fine with the default value of the input node, but it is not updating in the inputs of the modifier

Comment: Right, my mistake ! See the other answer :)

Comment: This does not answer how to change the value of the modifier (Geometry node) input, but how to change a "default_value" value of the group node contained in the modifier. This will have no effect on the value displayed in the Geometry Node

Comment: @NoobCat yes, as stated in the comment above I didn't understand the question. See the other answer